# Sandboxed solution deployed activated, in Site Collection Features but not in Manage site features?

Tags: 2010, deployment, sandbox-solution, solution-package, solution

I have a sandboxed feature I deployed successfully.  It is activated when I check in Site collection features, but when I go to Manage site features it is not there to activate.  What am I missing?  It is also not available as a webpart to add to a page?

Comment: What is the scope of the feature, and what is in it?  If you are deploying elements in the wrong scope(for example, a web template in a web-scoped feature), your feature may not show up.

Answer (score 1):

If the sandboxed solution package contains a Feature that is scoped to the site collection level, the Feature is activated automatically. Any Features that are scoped to the website level must be activated on the Manage site features page at /_layouts/managefeatures.aspx.

I think you scoped your SandBox to Site collection not the web level. The Feature scope is determined by the setting of the Scope attribute in the Feature element defined in the feature.xml file.

A sample Feature element tag is given below:

```
Feature Id="F62C96CF-79FD-44be-8882-E9BFBD199184" 
Title="Feature Title" 
Description="Feature Description" 
Version="1.0.0.0" 
Scope="Site" 
Hidden="false">
```

for web site level "Web Site scoped Feature (Scope="Web"):"

Answer (score 0):

A feature is either visible on sitecollection or site. So if you need it to be visible on the site you have to change scope in the feature xml..

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms436075.aspx for more.